# Android Emulator Stuck Equals (=) Phantom Keypress

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

For some reason, and only on my Dell Vostro 1000 laptop, the Android emulator keeps thinking I have the = key pressed and continually emits a string of "=====" equal signs.  This happens no matter what I'm doing in the emulator.  It responds to my manual keypresses as well, interspersing them.  It happens no matter which version of the Android system I run (2.1, 2.2, etc.)

Strangely, it happens even running the Android emulator via a remote desktop session where the remote desktop client is the laptop and the server is another PC running the emulator.  If I run the emulator on the other PC locally (not remote desktop,) the emulator functions fine!

This problem didn't occur when I first installed the SDK and as far as I know no other software has been installed since then.  I tried clicking the "clear user data" from the emulator launcher and still no effect.  I have also tried deleting the SDK directory and reinstalling it, but the effect is still there.

Update: I found another application that exhibits this behavior. ScummVM when opening a dialog to save the game also receives these phantom keypresses.  It persists in Windows 7.

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Maybe it's just a bug on your machine, try uninstalling and reinstalling. I seem to have the same configuration as yours, and no issue here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully fixed the problem with this odd procedure:  Remove the battery, hold down the power button for five seconds, release.  Wait five seconds, hold down the power button for five seconds, release.  Replace battery, hold down the power button for five seconds, release.  Wait five seconds, hold down the power button for five seconds, release.  If the problem returns, repeat this process.

It's definitely not an Android bug.  If you want an easy way to demonstrate the bug and verify that you've fixed it, go to http://tryhaskell.org and you should see the phantom key presses in the "Type Haskell expressions in here." window.

Comment: Thank you. Solved my issue with my idle time-out as well. Now my screensaver/stand-by works.